# How to document this code properly in JSDoc3

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How to document this code properly in JSDoc3?

```
var Foo,
    doFoo;

/**
 * What JSDoc string should go here ...
 */
doFoo = function () {};

/**
 * @constructor
 */
Foo = function () {};

/**
 * ... and here ..
 */
Foo.doFoo = doFoo;

/**
 * ... and here ..
 */
Foo.prototype.doBar = doFoo;

/**
 * ... and here?
 */
Foo.prototype.doBoo = doFoo;
```

Help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The tag you are probably looking for is `@method` (http://usejsdoc.org/tags-method.html), which lets the parser know that something that might not look like a function is actually a function.

You can also use `@link` (http://usejsdoc.org/tags-link.html) to point to the description of the original function declaration if you don't want to duplicate descriptions.